ambiguity error when adding pivot to existing SQL oracle statement
 SELECT
     *
     FROM
     (
     SELECT
    ordr.program,
    ordr.order_id,
    ordr.part_no,
    ordr.order_no,
    ordr.actual_start_date,
    ser.serial_no,
    oper.asgnd_machine_id,
    oper.time_stamp,
    oper.updt_userid,
    oper.oper_status,
    oper.oper_no ,
      
    CASE
      WHEN oper.oper_no IN ('1234') THEN 'paint_bike'  
 
    END AS oper_type
  
    FROM
    sfmfg.sfwid_order_desc ordr
    LEFT JOIN sfmfg.sfwid_serial_desc ser
    ON ordr.order_id = ser.order_id
    LEFT JOIN sfmfg.sfwid_oper_desc oper
     ON ordr.order_id = oper.order_id
     AND oper.step_key = -1
     AND ordr.program IN ('bike')
     AND oper.oper_no IN ('1234')
    WHERE
    ordr.actual_start_date > TO_DATE('08/01/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
     AND ordr.part_no LIKE '123'
     AND ser.serial_no LIKE '123')

and I want to add this pivot to the end of it.
    PIVOT (
    MAX(asgnd_machine_id) AS asgnd_machine_id,
    MAX(time_stamp) AS time_stamp,
    MAX(updt_userid) AS updt_userid,
    MAX(oper_status) AS oper_status FOR oper_type IN ('bike_Cutting' AS bike_Cutting, 'bike_Prep' AS         bike_Prep,
       )

I am trying to get the pivot to work but I'm getting column ambiguously defined errors for my first select statement when I add alias such as this for the first select statement
 SELECT 
    a1.program,
    a1.order_id,
    a1.customer_description,
    a1.stiffener_type,
    a1.mold_tool_no,
    a1.part_no,
    a1.order_no,
    a1.actual_start_date,
    a1.serial_no,
    a1.asgnd_machine_id,
    a1.time_stamp,
    a1.updt_userid,
    a1.oper_status,
    a1.plan_title,
    a1.oper_type  

it gives me invalid identifier errors

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When you PIVOT columns you need to combine the aliases from the FOR clause and the aggregation clause of the PIVOT:
SELECT a1.program,
       a1.order_id,
       -- a1.customer_description, -- These 4 columns are not in your query.
       -- a1.stiffener_type,
       -- a1.mold_tool_no,
       --a1.plan_title,
       a1.part_no,
       a1.order_no,
       a1.actual_start_date,
       a1.serial_no,
       a1.bike_cutting_asgnd_machine_id, -- combine the aliases for these columns
       a1.bike_cutting_time_stamp,
       a1.bike_cutting_updt_userid,
       a1.bike_cutting_oper_status,
       a1.bike_prep_asgnd_machine_id,
       a1.bike_prep_time_stamp,
       a1.bike_prep_updt_userid,
       a1.bike_prep_oper_status
FROM (
  SELECT ordr.program,
         ordr.order_id,
         ordr.part_no,
         ordr.order_no,
         ordr.actual_start_date,
         ser.serial_no,
         oper.oper_no,
         -- pivot
         oper.asgnd_machine_id,
         oper.time_stamp,
         oper.updt_userid,
         oper.oper_status,
         CASE
         WHEN oper.oper_no IN ('1234') THEN 'paint_bike'  
         WHEN oper.oper_no IN ('5678') THEN 'bike_Cutting'  
         WHEN oper.oper_no IN ('9999') THEN 'bike_Prep'  
         END AS oper_type
  FROM   /*sfmfg.*/sfwid_order_desc ordr
         LEFT JOIN /*sfmfg.*/sfwid_serial_desc ser
         ON ordr.order_id = ser.order_id
         LEFT JOIN /*sfmfg.*/sfwid_oper_desc oper
         ON     ordr.order_id = oper.order_id
            AND oper.step_key = -1
            AND ordr.program IN ('bike')
            AND oper.oper_no IN ('1234')
  WHERE  ordr.actual_start_date > TO_DATE('08/01/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND    ordr.part_no LIKE '123'
  AND    ser.serial_no LIKE '123'
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(asgnd_machine_id) AS asgnd_machine_id,
  MAX(time_stamp) AS time_stamp,
  MAX(updt_userid) AS updt_userid,
  MAX(oper_status) AS oper_status
  FOR oper_type IN (
    'bike_Cutting' AS bike_Cutting,
    'bike_Prep'    AS bike_Prep
  )
) a1

fiddle
